# Combining results of subscale predictions to ascertain overall scale predictions

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

I am performing a generic inverse variance random-effects meta-analysis, in order to examine the predictive value of childhood trauma on depression in adulthood. When a full scale of childhood trauma (e.g.: CTQ) is used to predict depression in adulthood, the statistic given can be in the form of an odds ratio, Peason r correlation, beta value, etc, depending on whether the IV and DV are operationalized as continous or dichotemous values, and depending on the type of analysis peformed.

However, some studies do not report the relationship of the overall score of the IV (e.g.: CTQ full scale score) with the DV, generating a singular effect estimate. Instead they seperately report the relationship of the subscale scores of the IV (e.g. CTQ emotional abuse subscale score) with the DV, generating multiple effect estimates (one for each subscale). My question is whether these subscale effect estimates can be summed/combined to form a singular effect estimate for the entire scale.

I imagine that the answer will depend on the effect estimate used, so I will give examples on the 3 main effect estimates that I have encountered.

Example 1: ODDS RATIOS (from a multivariate logistic regression model, or multiple singular logistic regression models)
CTQ physical abuse subscale - depression OR = 1.12
CTQ emotional abuse subscale - depression OR = 1.53
CTQ sexual abuse subscale - depression OR = 1.37
CTQ physical neglect subscale - depression OR 1.10
CTQ emotional neglect subscale - depression OR 2.13

Is there a way to combine the effect sizes of these subscales to get a singular effect size for: CTQ scale - depression OR = ?

Example 2: PEARSON R CORRELATIONS (bivariate corelations given in a correlation matrix)
CTQ physical abuse subscale - depression r = .17
CTQ emotional abuse subscale - depression r = .33
CTQ sexual abuse subscale - depression r = .27
CTQ physical neglect subscale - depression r = .13
CTQ emotional neglect subscale - depression r = .11

Is there a way to combine the effect sizes of these subscales to get a singular effect size for: CTQ scale - depression r = ?
*For this example I saw a previous answer on this forum suggesting that it is appropriate to convert all r values to z values, sum them, and then divide by the number of predictor variables, essentially obtaining a mean z value. Then converting the mean z value to a mean r value, which is an acceptable estimate of the predictive value of the full scale. Essentially (z1+z2+z3+z4+z5)/5 = mean z, which is then converted to mean r, to be used in CTQ scale - depression overall r value.
Is this correct?
Is this method statistically unsound if some of the subscales have negative r values?

Example 3:BETAS (from a multivariate linear regression model)
CTQ physical abuse subscale - depression b = .15
CTQ emotional abuse subscale - depression b = .23
CTQ sexual abuse subscale - depression b = .15
CTQ physical neglect subscale - depression b = .17
CTQ emotional neglect subscale - depression b = .11

Is there a way to combine the effect sizes of these subscales to get a singular effect size for: CTQ scale - depression b = ?
This question can apply to standardized or unstandardized betas, as usually both are reported.
If there are negative betas, does this change the possibility of combining them (if there even is a possibility).

I understand that overall predictive value for the CTQ on depression is easy to obtain if working with the raw data, as one would simply regress/correlate the full scale scores on/with the DV, but in this instance I am only working with the somewhat limited reporting of results from papers. In most instances where this is an issue, only the values of the effect estimates, their SE, direction, and significance are reported.
I wuld hate to exclude papers simply because of insufficient reporting (relative to the effect estimate of the relationship that I am attempting to extract), however if I do combine the subscale effect estimate values to get my variable of interest, I need to do so in a statistically sound manner.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one can combine multiple estimates by averaging them (but for odds ratios, one would first log transform them before taking the average). However, the difficult part is computing the correct sampling variance of such an average. If the estimates are independent, then the sampling variance of $\bar{y} = (y_1 + y_2 + y_3)/3$ would simply be $\mbox{Var}[\bar{y}] = (v_1 + v_2 + v_3)/9$, where $y_i$ is the $i$th estimate and $v_i$ the corresponding sampling variance.

But these estimates are not independent, since they are based on the same sample. Roughly, to the degree that the subscale values are correlated, so will be the estimates. If one knows knows what the correlation between the estimates is, then one can compute the $\mbox{Var}[\bar{y}]$. See Box 24.1 in Borenstein et al. (2009) (the book *Introduction to meta-analysis*). The problem is that you typically do not have information about the correlation between the different subscales (this is not typically reported in studies). But one might still be able to make an educated guess about the correlations (from other studies or own data) and use those in computing the sampling variance of the average.